# Java How to split() if string contain space or "-" and a character before or after

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a string only if it contains the character "-" or if it contains a space, but only if a character exists before and after the "-" or the space.

Example:

```
" test" -> Dont split
"-test" -> Dont split
"test test" -> split
" test test" -> split       
"test-" -> dont split
"test-test" -> split
"a-test" -> split
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to use a regular expression to do this? Manually do the split yourself? What about `"ab -cd` - how do you split that? Or `"- -"`?

Comment: I have tied some regular expression but all my attempts were failures. I use the split() method of java. For ""ab-cd" i want to split into ["ab"] ["cd"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This RegEx matches any " " or "-" (or more to handle multiple spaces or dashes) which is surrounded by a word character.

```
(?<=\w)[ -]+(?=\w)
```

### Example

```
final String regex = "(?<=\\w)[ -]+(?=\\w)";

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(" test".split(regex)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("-test".split(regex)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("test test".split(regex)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(" test test".split(regex)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("test-".split(regex)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("test-test".split(regex)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a-test".split(regex)));
```

#### Output

```
[ test]
[-test]
[test, test]
[ test, test]
[test-]
[test, test]
[a, test]
```